# Plot Nsolve moment on beam

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have been sitting for hours trying different commands changing the Plot line without success. I get correct output when I use Nsolve, but an empty plot using the same Nsolve values.

Everything works fine until the last plot sequence.

can somebody clarify why I get empty graph when I plot?

```
Remove["Global`*"]

L1 = 6;

L2 = L1;

F = 18;

q = 12;

Q = q L1;

I = 1042.3 10^-8;

E = 200 10^9;

E I

\[CapitalTheta]A = (MA L1)/(3 E I) + (MB L1)/(6 E I) + (Q (L2)^2)/(
24 E I);

\[CapitalTheta]B1 = (MA L1)/(6 E I) + (MB L1)/(3 E I) + (Q (L2)^2)/(
24 E I);

\[CapitalTheta]B2 = ((MB L2)/(3 E I) + (MC L2)/(6 E I) - (
F (L1 - 3)^2)/(4 E I));

\[CapitalTheta]C = (MB L2)/(6 E I) + (MC L2)/(3 E I) - (
F (L1 - 3)^2)/(4 E I);

Rv = NSolve[\[CapitalTheta]A ==
0 && \[CapitalTheta]B1 == -\[CapitalTheta]B2 && \[CapitalTheta]C ==
 0]

Plot[Rv, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x [m]", "M(x) [kNm]"},
ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", Filling -> Axis,
PlotLabel -> "M(x)-diagram"]
```

So the issue is basically the last code below:

```
Plot[Rv, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x [m]", "M(x) [kNm]"},
ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", Filling -> Axis,
PlotLabel -> "M(x)-diagram"]
```

[image: All i get is this]
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked what Rv looks like though? NSolve will return a list of replacement rules. You can't plot those directly.

Comment: To add to @MarcoB there's another problem, namely that you used `E` and `I` as parameters to assign them numerical values. They are built-in symbols, the number $e$ and the imaginary unit respectively.